# Continuously print output of GitPython git.execute()

Tags: python, logging, progress, gitpython

I'm running a command with GitPython `git.execute()`. Currently, I'm writing the return value to a window. Because the command takes some time, the window will not show any progress for a few seconds and then write all the output once the command completes.

I want to continuously print output to the window to show the user what's happening. I have implemented a `logging.Logger` for this, but I don't know how to connect the `git.execute()` output to it. So how can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can natively stream output to a logger. You would need to write a custom implementation.